# Insert Array_list values into another empty Array_list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, arraylist

I have an array list that contains values, and another array list which is empty (with limited length). I want to insert the values of the first array into the other array, maintaining the limited length.

**Example:**

```
lst = []*10 // initialized 

lst_with_values = [43,434,3,4,5,76,3,5,19,3,1,3] // length  = 12
```

I want to insert the values of `lst_with_values` array into `lst` so it looks like this:

```
print(lst)
```

**Output:**

```
[43, 434, 3, 4, 5, 76, 3, 5, 19, 3]
```

Comment: for lines containing code, you should indent with 4 spaces in your post. This will make your post more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3 you can slice and assign your list that way with ease:

```
    size = 10
    lst = []
    lst_with_values = [43,434,3,4,5,76,3,5,19,3,1,3]
    lst = lst_with_values[:size] #this assigns values from 0 to size
    print(lst)
```

Comment: This will assign elements 0 to size-1 so you will get 10 elements

Comment: I think I like your answer better :/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your `lst` does not contain 10 items. You can try something like:

```
lst = [0 for i in range(10)]
```

To create an array of ten 0's. Then to input only the first 10 items of `lst_with_values` you can do something like:

```
for i in range(0, len(lst_with_values)):
    try:
        lst[i] = lst_with_values[i]
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Or more simply you can just index slice the values out

```
lst = lst_with_values[0:10]
```